# Group by percentage in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I try to create the following SQL query in LINQ to use in my ASP MVC project:

```
SELECT State, (Count(a.State)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From myTable))
FROM myTable a
GROUP BY a.State
```

What I have so far:

```
var data = db.myTable.GroupBy(fu => fu.State)
        .Select(g => new { Label = g.Key, Value = g.Key * 100 / g.Count() })
        .ToList();
```

The calculation is not correct. Have to get LINQ producing the same results as SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably this:-

```
 Value = g.Count() * 100 / db.myTable.Count()
```

This seems to be equivalent of your SQL query.

So your complete query should look like:-

```
var data = db.myTable.GroupBy(fu => fu.State)
         .Select(g => new { Label = g.Key, Value = g.Count() * 100 / db.myTable.Count() })
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var data = db.myTable.GroupBy(fu => fu.State)
        .Select(g => new { Label = g.Key, Value = g.Count() * 100 / db.myTable.Count() })
        .ToList();
```

`g.Count()` is going to give you `Count(a.State)` value and `db.myTable.Count()` the total of rows in that table